# Spyder fails on Anaconda 2-4.3.21/2-4.4.0 - ImportError: No module named > shutil_get_terminal_size

Tags: ipython, anaconda, spyder

From the Anaconda command prompt I launch Spyder. Spyder launches, even loading and issuing a warning that my previous session crashed and that I should consider resetting (which I eventually did without result). The process carries on and then hangs on forever, failing to start (i.e. open the working windows with code, console, variables etc.)

Tried to reset Spyder

> Spyder --reset

Spyder resets properly but still fails to start

Spyder Version: 3.1.4
Python Version: 2.7.13
Anaconda Version: 4.3.21
Qt Version: 5.6.2
PyQt Version: 5.6.0
Operating system: Windows 10

Then I uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda this time Version: 2.4.4.0. Spyder launched once satisfactorily only to crash ever after.

Investigating the process further, it cought up the following error:

> spyder --show-console
>
> (C:\Users\me\Anaconda2) C:\Users\me>spyder --show-console Traceback
>   (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py",
>   line 3011, in main mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args) File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py",
>   line 2913, in run_spyder main.setup() File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py",
>   line 873, in setup from spyder.plugins.ipythonconsole import
>   IPythonConsole File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole.py",
>   line 60, in  from spyder.widgets.ipythonconsole import ClientWidget
>   File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\widgets\ipythonconsole_init_.py",
>   line 12, in  from .debugging import DebuggingWidget File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\widgets\ipythonconsole\debugging.py",
>   line 16, in  from qtconsole.rich_jupyter_widget import
>   RichJupyterWidget File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\rich_jupyter_widget.py",
>   line 14, in  from .jupyter_widget import JupyterWidget File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\jupyter_widget.py",
>   line 19, in  from IPython.lib.lexers import IPythonLexer,
>   IPython3Lexer File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython_init_.py", line 48,
>   in  from .core.application import Application File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py",
>   line 25, in  from IPython.core import release, crashhandler File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\crashhandler.py",
>   line 28, in  from IPython.core import ultratb File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py",
>   line 128, in  from IPython.utils.terminal import get_terminal_size
>   File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\terminal.py",
>   line 22, in  from backports.shutil_get_terminal_size import
>   get_terminal_size as _get_terminal_size ImportError: No module named
>   shutil_get_terminal_size
>
> (C:\Users\me\Anaconda2) C:\Users\me>

So then I tried the following:

> (C:\Users\me\Anaconda2) C:\Users\me>conda install
>   shutil_get_terminal_size Fetching package metadata ...........
>
> PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current win-64 channels:
>
> shutil_get_terminal_size Close matches found; did you mean one of
>   these?
>
> shutil_get_terminal_size: get_terminal_size

Btw Spyder issue or Anaconda issue?

So anway I proceeded to install get_terminal_size and have a go at it

> (C:\Users\me\Anaconda2) C:\Users\me>conda install get_terminal_size
>   Fetching package metadata ........... Solving package specifications:
>   .

All requested packages already installed.
packages in environment at C:\Users\me\Anaconda2:

get_terminal_size 1.0.0 py27_0

Then tries again to launch in the command prompt

> spyder

which fails including trying once again after resetting

> spyder --reset

Investigating further

> spyder --show-console

results in me returning straight back to square one

> (C:\Users\me\Anaconda2) C:\Users\me>spyder --show console Traceback
>   (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py",
>   line 3011, in main mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args) File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py",
>   line 2913, in run_spyder main.setup() File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py",
>   line 873, in setup from spyder.plugins.ipythonconsole import
>   IPythonConsole File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole.py",
>   line 60, in  from spyder.widgets.ipythonconsole import ClientWidget
>   File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\widgets\ipythonconsole_init_.py",
>   line 12, in  from .debugging import DebuggingWidget File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\widgets\ipythonconsole\debugging.py",
>   line 16, in  from qtconsole.rich_jupyter_widget import
>   RichJupyterWidget File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\rich_jupyter_widget.py",
>   line 14, in  from .jupyter_widget import JupyterWidget File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\jupyter_widget.py",
>   line 19, in  from IPython.lib.lexers import IPythonLexer,
>   IPython3Lexer File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython_init_.py", line 48,
>   in  from .core.application import Application File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py",
>   line 25, in  from IPython.core import release, crashhandler File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\crashhandler.py",
>   line 28, in  from IPython.core import ultratb File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py",
>   line 128, in  from IPython.utils.terminal import get_terminal_size
>   File
>   "C:\Users\me\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\terminal.py",
>   line 22, in  from backports.shutil_get_terminal_size import
>   get_terminal_size as _get_terminal_size ImportError: No module named
>   shutil_get_terminal_size

PS: I have used with satisfaction Anaconda and Spyder for months now without any issue, cannot understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a solution which was to conda reinstall ipython and pip reinstall backports.shutil_get_terminal_size :

```
conda uninstall ipython
conda install python
pip uninstall backports.shutil_get_terminal_size
pip install backports.shutil_get_terminal_size
```

For more info I suggest to consult the following issues:

- [ipython/ipython/#9656](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9656)
- ipython/ipython/#9815 (I cannot post more than 2 links so google it up!)
- [chrippa/backports.shutil_get_terminal_size/#9](https://github.com/chrippa/backports.shutil_get_terminal_size/issues/9)

For some reason however Spyder then issues a warning that nbconvert isn't installed whereas both conda and pip install nbconvert show that nbconvert is fully installed and up to date...

> Spyder dependancy missing nbconvert >=4.0: None (NOK) Please install
>   to prevent this message displaying Fetching package metadata
>   ........... Solving package specifications: .

```
conda install nbconvert
```

> All requested packages already installed. packages in environment at
>   C:\Users\me\Anaconda2:
>
> nbconvert 5.2.1 py27_0

```
pip install nbconvert
```

> Requirement already satisfied: nbconvert in c:\users\me\anaconda2\lib\site-packages Requirement already satisfied: mistune!=0.6 in c:\users\me\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in c:\users\me\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\users\me\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.2 in c:\users\me\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: jupyter_core in c:\users\me\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: nbformat in c:\users\me\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints>=0.2.2 in c:\users\me\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: bleach in c:\users\me\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: pandocfilters>=1.4.1 in c:\users\me\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: testpath in c:\users\me\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from nbconvert)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\me\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from jinja2->nbconvert)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\me\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from bleach->nbconvert)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: html5lib!=0.9999,!=0.99999,<0.99999999,>=0.999 in c:\users\me\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from bleach->nbconvert)